# I've spent hours trying to get these array keys into variables but everything I try is not working

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have an array of all possible combinations of values, a bit like working out what monetary values I could make with only certain coins. Now I have an array built but much of the useful data are keys and not values.

A small snippet is below:
Each root key is an array with keys total, denomination and quantity. Each of the quantities multiplied by the denominations total the total. While I've been able to access the total easily enough I just can't get a handle on the denominations and the quantities.

It's my plan to output to separate radio buttons like so:

```
foreach($array as $arr)
{
    echo '<input type="radio" name="name" value="'.$arr[$total].'">';
    foreach($arr[denom] as $index => $d)
    {
        echo $d[qty][$index].' x '.$d[denom][$index].' = '.($qty[$index]*$denom[$index]).'<br>';
    }
}
```

Here's the array I have, any help would be much appreciate, I'm usually great at this bot it's driving me crazy

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [total] => 105
            [denom] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 105
                )

            [qty] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [total] => 210
            [denom] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 105
                )

            [qty] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [total] => 300
            [denom] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 300
                )

            [qty] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [total] => 405
            [denom] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 300
                    [1] => 105
                )

            [qty] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [total] => 500
            [denom] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 500
                )

            [qty] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [total] => 605
            [denom] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 500
                    [1] => 105
                )

            [qty] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )
```

Comment: You would be well-served by turning up your error reporting level by putting `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script.  It's pretty clear that you're running with a lower error reporting level, or have turned the display of errors off.  Your code should be giving you *plenty* of warnings, and these may be of great help to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constant non-numeric array indices should be written like any other string, i.e. encapsulated in quotes.

```
foreach($array as $arr) {
    echo '<input type="radio" name="name" value="'.$arr['total'].'">';
    foreach($arr['denom'] as $index => $d){
        for ($j = 0;$j < count($denom);$j++) {
            echo $d['qty'][$j].' x '.$d['denom'][$j].' = ';
            echo ($d['qty'][$j]*$d['denom'][$j]) . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I see the error of my ways not, excellent, thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

First format your array like this in my code, add 6, 7 array elements. I modify for loop too.

```
<?php
$array = array(2 => array('total' => 105, 'denom' => array(0 => 105), 'qty' => array(0 => 1)),
                             3 => array('total' => 210, 'denom' => array(0 => 105), 'qty' => array(0 => 2)),
                             4 => array('total' => 300, 'denom' => array(0 => 300), 'qty' => array(0 => 1)),
                             5 => array('total' => 405, 'denom' => array(0 => 300, 1 => 105), 'qty' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 1)),
                             );

foreach($array as $arr)
{
//var_dump($arr);
    echo '<input type="radio" name="name" value="'.$arr['total'].'">';
    foreach($arr['denom'] as $index => $d)
    {
        echo $arr['qty'][$index].' x '.$d.' = '.($arr['qty'][$index]*$d).'<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The array representation in the question is outputted by `print_r` and probably read from a database or so.

Comment: Then use only modified for loop with your array and this must work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response but just making the array took a long time and I've been tring to sort and sift it into a better structure but I jsut couldn't!